# In MongoDB, how do I use a field in the document as input to a $geoWithin/$centerSphere expression?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, geospatial

I'm trying to write a MongoDB query that searches for documents within a radius centered on a specified location.

The query below works. It finds all documents that are within `searching.radius` radians of `searching.coordinates`.

However what I would like to do is add the current documents `allowed_radius` value to the `searching.radius` value, so that the allowed sphere is actually larger.

How can I phrase this query to make this possible?

**Present Query**:

```
collection.aggregate([
        {
            $project:{
                location: "$location",
                allowed_radius: "$allowed_radius"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                $and:
                    [
                        { location: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ searching.coordinates, searching.radius ] }}},
                        {...},
                    ...]
                ...}
]);
```

**What I am trying to do (pseudo-query)**:

```
collection.aggregate([
        {
            $project:{
                location: "$location",
                allowed_radius: "$allowed_radius"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                $and:
                    [
                        { location: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ searching.coordinates, { $add: [searching.radius, $allowed_radius]} ] }}},
                        {...},
                    ...]
                ...}
]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried using `$geoWithin / $centerSphere`, but couldn't make it work this way.

Here is another way of doing so, using the [**$geoNear**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) operator:

Given this input:

```
db.collection.insert({
  "airport": "LGW",
  "id": 1,
  "location": { type: "Point", coordinates: [-0.17818, 51.15609] },
  "allowed_radius": 100
})
db.collection.insert({
  "airport": "LGW",
  "id": 2,
  "location": { type: "Point", coordinates: [-0.17818, 51.15609] },
  "allowed_radius": 0
})
db.collection.insert({
  "airport": "ORY",
  "id": 3,
  "location": { type: "Point", coordinates: [2.35944, 48.72528] },
  "allowed_radius": 10
})
```

And this index (which is required for $geoNear):

```
db.collection.createIndex( { location : "2dsphere" } )
```

With searching.radius = 1000:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $geoNear: {
    near: { "type" : "Point", "coordinates":  [7.215872, 43.658411] },
    distanceField: "distance",
    spherical: true,
    distanceMultiplier: 0.001
  }},
  { $addFields: { radius: { "$add": ["$allowed_radius", 1000] } } },
  { $addFields: { isIn: { "$subtract": ["$distance", "$radius" ] } } },
  { $match: { isIn: { "$lte": 0 } } }
])
```

would return documents with id 1 (distance=1002 <= radius=1000+100) and 3 (distance=676 <= radius=1000+10) and discard id 2 (distance=1002 > 1000+0).

The `distanceMultiplier` parameter is used to bring back units to km.

$geoNear must be the first stage of an aggregation (due to the usage of the index I think), but one of the parameters of $geoNear is a match query on other fields.

Even if it requires the geospacial index, you can add additional dimensions to the index.

$geoNear doesn't take the location field as an argument, because it requires the collection to have a geospacial index. Thus $geoNear implicitly uses as location field (whatever the name of the field) the one indexed.

Finally, I'm pretty sure the last stages can be simplified.

The $geoNear stage is only used to project the distance on each record:

```
{ "airport" : "ORY", "distance" : 676.5790971238937, "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 2.35944, 48.72528 ] }, "allowed_radius" : 10, "id" : 3 }
{ "airport" : "LGW", "distance" : 1002.3351814526812, "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -0.17818, 51.15609 ] }, "allowed_radius" : 100, "id" : 1 }
{ "airport" : "LGW", "distance" : 1002.3351814526812, "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -0.17818, 51.15609 ] }, "allowed_radius" : 0, "id" : 2 }
```

In fact, the geoNear operator requires the use of the `distanceField` argument, which is used to project the computed distance on each record for the next stages of the query. At the end of the aggregation, returned records look like:

```
{
  "airport" : "ORY",
  "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 2.35944, 48.72528 ] },
  "allowed_radius" : 10,
  "id" : 3,
  "distance" : 676.5790971238937,
  "radius" : 1010,
  "isIn" : -333.4209028761063
}
```

If necessary, you can remove fields produced by the query for the query (distance, radius, isIn) with a final $project stage. For instance: `{"$project":{"distance":0}}`

Comment: Thanks! Interesting idea! Does the distance field get persisted or does it apply just per query?

Comment: And in the query, what part of it says "use the `location` field of the document to compare against" ?

Comment: You're welcome! The `distance field` is projected and made available for the next stages of the aggregation, and is returned within output records (can be removed with a $project stage when not needed in the pipeline anymore). But records on the collection are not updated with this field (not sure if I answer the question). The `location field` (whatever its name) is not an argument of the $geoNear operator because it's implicitly deduced from the compulsory geospacial index. I've edited the answer with a bit more details.

Comment: Thanks @Xavier. I've been having some trouble getting it to work and I realize part of the problem is that `geoNear` allows for only one `2dsphere` index and in fact each of my documents have two locations. So this answer is great but it actually doesn't totally work in my situation